# Assembly inline in C error reference

Tags: c, gcc, inline-assembly

i need to do that in C, i'm working with a gcc version 2.95.2:

```
move.b #$01, $3FFFFF;
```

but if i put this:

```
 __asm__ ( "move.b #$01, $3FFFFF;" );
```

i got:

```
/cygdrive/c/NeoGeo_Development/NeoDev/tmp/main.o(.text+0x355): undefined referen
ce to `$01'
```

and

```
/cygdrive/c/NeoGeo_Development/NeoDev/tmp/main.o(.text+0x355): undefined referen
ce to `$3FFFFF'
```

How can i do correctly?

Comment: Try `0x` instead of `$`. Or you could probably just use something like `*(volatile char*)(0x3FFFFF) = 1;` instead of the assembly code.

Comment: Yes guys you are right if i put 0x it goes...do u assure me it's the same of dollar sign?

Answer (score 0):

Try `0x` instead of `$`. Or you could probably just use something like

```
 *(volatile char*)(0x3FFFFF) = 1;
```

instead of the assembly code. –  Michael